# React Native - Unable to update a new state inside items individually

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, mapping, increment

I have pulled data from an api which has a list of exercises inside, here is an example exericse object.

```
    {
        pivot_id:1,
        id:1,
        image_path: "exercise\/images\/q3YaO7uuFYgZDFg7fnVpn3eYxrb5oUZeKwE6mNf7.png",
        name:"Smitham PLC",
        duration:423,
        duration_per_rep:5,
        intensity:{
          id:2,
          intensity: "Moderate Resistance Training",
          met_value:4.5
        },
        image:"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/fitness-concierge\/exercise\/images\/q3YaO7uuFYgZDFg7fnVpn3eYxrb5oUZeKwE6mNf7.png",
        kcal:5,
  },
```

I have created a customDuration state with a default value of 60, which I want to add to each exercise object by using a button to add a duration with an increment of 30 seconds. However, I am having an issue with updating just one specific item.

For example, I have two items rendered, and when I go to press the + button to add 30 seconds to the exercise it does, it goes from 60 - 90, but then when I go and add some time on the second item in the list it will go from 60 - 120 which is were the problem is occurring.

```
 addDuration(item, index) {
    let newArray = [...this.state.warm_up_exercises];
    newArray[index] = { 
        ...newArray[index], 
        customDuration: this.state.customDuration = this.state.customDuration + 30,
        storeValues: true,
        workoutStoreType: 'duration',
    };
    this.setState({
        warm_up_exercises: newArray,
    });
}
```

Above is the function I am using to add a duration to the exercise, I have tried to do item.customDuration = item.customDuration + 30 but I just get NaN in the console.

In my mapping function I have the custom duration showing like this

```
<Text>{{ item.customDuration }}</Text>
```

I've been struggling with this a couple of days now so much help would be really appreciated. All I am trying to achieve is to just make it so when I add the values to the array, it will update that item and have no effect on the other items.

Additional Code to provide more context:

```
My constructor:

constructor(props) {
  super(props) {
    warm_up_exercises: [],
    selected_warm_up_exercises: [],
    repsValue: 0,
    setsValue: 0,
    restValue: 0,
    workoutStoreType: "",
    customDuration: 60,
  }
}
Were I call the function: 

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addDuration(item, index)}>
   <AntDesign name="pluscircle" size={22} color={Colours.type.primary_colour}  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not properly initialising your state. It should be an object, which has the exercise array as a property. Write it like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props) {
    this.state = {
     exercises: [],
     repsValue: 0,
     setsValue: 0,
     restValue: 0,
     workoutStoreType: "",
     customDuration: 60,
    }
  }
}
```

Every time you increment the state you are not just mutating it, but you also put customDuration to every entity. The problem lies here:

```
customDuration: this.state.customDuration = this.state.customDuration + 30
```

In order to do it right, you just need to write:

```
customDuration: this.state.customDuration + 30
```

And then, to increment the state you should do it separately :

```
this.setState({
        exercises: newArray,
        customDuration: this.state.customDuration + 30
    });
```

In case you need to have a customDuration to every item you also need to change the state in the same way, but with a bit of a twist:

```
addDuration(item, index) {
    let newArray = [...this.state.exercises]
    newArray[index] = {
        ...newArray[index],
        customDuration: newArray[index].customDuration ? newArray[index].customDuration + 30 : 90,
        storeValues: true,
        workoutStoreType: 'duration',
    };
    this.setState({
        exercises: newArray,
    });
}
```

And then remove customDuration from the initial state. This way you will increment by 30 and put 90 the first time you increment

Comment: Thank you I have implemented it that way. But the customDuration value is still being updating on the next item. So when I update the first item from 60 - 90, and then go and update the next item in the array it goes from 60 - 120. Do I need to add an [index] to the end of the state or add item.customDuration somewhere in that function?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. I thought you want to have a global duration, which increases, when you increment. Please tell me if you want to have a customDuration for each exercise and I will update my answer. Also, I see now, that there is a problem with the way you init your state

Comment: Yes thats what my aim is, is to have a customDuration for each exercise, so when I increment the customDuration for one exercise, it will only update that one and have no effect on the other exercises so it just updates them individually. Apologies if it came across that I wanted it globally.

Comment: @TrevorStrong I updated my answer, tell me if I understood properly

Comment: You've got the right idea, but having the customDuration is optional. Ignore that exercises array. This is why I am wanting to get it so it adds the customDuration to one exercise only because its optional so I do not want it to add every item if I update only one exercise. The this.state.customDuration value has a default value of 60 seconds, which is want I want, however when I want to update exercise A, and decide to add an extra 60 seconds I update the state to 120 seconds, but then I when I go to exercise B and go and update it it goes from 60- 150 so it is carrying the value over.

Comment: I've got an api which I call, which then I use an array to setState to the JSON response. Then I map over the array to display the exercises. This is where I have set different values just not customDuration, customSets & customReps. But my aim is so when the user wants to add duration, then i add the customDuration to that specific exercise. If the user wants then to add reps & sets to the next exercise, then the customReps and customSets values are stored. So it is all optional for the user. And if the user doesn't add either, I will use the default duration in the json object.

Comment: Ok, so initially every exercise has different seconds, but then when you add, you want to add a constant customDuration? If that is the case, then replace the '30' at the end of my answer with the constant duration, which you can set in the state when you receive it. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, all exercises have a default duration of 60 seconds, however, the user can add their own duration which will be stored as customDuration incase they want to do less than 60 seconds or more than. They can also be add customReps and customSets. This is why I want to be able to just add a value specifically to an item in the array, and not the rest of the items. I have added an image over the screen that I want to implement the changes on just to give you a better idea of what I want to acheive.

Comment: As far as I understand this is exactly what my last snippet does. We receive an index, we spread the array and increment the customDuration of the item, that corresponds to that index. In that case the custom duration will be unique to that item. Did you change your state like the snippet in the beginning of my answer?

Comment: Oh sorry I had not it is storing the items individually which is great! But I have to press the button twice in order for the value of customDuration to increment from 60 to 90. Which causes another issue as when I press the button the first time the initial value (60) does not change, then I press it again and it goes to 90 but the value being stored in the console shows 60.

Comment: So, I edited my answer, because it had an error. It needs to put it at 90 if it does not exist, because the first increment will always be 90, right? Also, how are you console logging the state? this.setState is async, so in order to view the results you need to console.log in a callback as a second argument of setState. Like that:
this.setState({}, () => {console.log(this.state}})

Comment: I am not logging the state i am logging the exercises array after the this.setState({exericses: newArray }) has been set so I can see the updated values being stored

Comment: Well, exercises is part of the state, so we cannot count on console.logs for seeing the state change. console.log the state in a callback like I showed and tell me what happens

Comment: Ah I have logged the array inside a callback and the and the correct data is being shown. It is interesting comparing a normal console.log(this.state.exercises) and the one inside a callback as the console.log inside a callback has the data being shown straightaway.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Did you do anything different from my answer? If so, please tell me so I can correct it

Comment: No your answer done the job. My assumption was that I need to create a state of customDuration in order to add it into the array but the way you have it done it is great. Thank you for your help you.